# Come together singing let it be

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> Come together singing let it be,
> And gather that which is free,
>
> As a child a simple weapon,
> To best not be in possession,
>
> Follow so you can ride with me,
> Let us play and move exactly,
>
> A no-good-doer finishes it,
> Forging not ahead makes your commit,
>
> A mystery is all I can see,
> As you dress me up so nicely.

What am I?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the word you are looking for is

> Band

Come together singing let it be,

> Referencing songs from The Beatles - a musical band. 'Come together' also puts us in mind of 'band together'.

And gather that which is free,

> A band is a thin strip of material which can be used to tie things together, e.g, a hairband.

As a child a simple weapon,

> I think this refers to an elastic band which can be used in children's weapons like a slingshot or toy gun.

To best not be in possession,

> This could be either **banned** (a homophone) or contra**band**.

Follow so you can ride with me,

> Bandwagon.

Let us play and move exactly,

> Marching band

A no-good-doer finishes it,

> Putting 'it' on he end of band creates bandit - a no-good-doer

Forging not ahead makes your commit,

> I think this is a play on words and refers to a wedding band (wedding ring). 'Forging not' sounds like 'tying the knot' as in 'wedding' and putting it ahead of band gives the result, a sign of commitment.

A mystery is all I can see,

> Bandanna **(as suggested by OP)**

As you dress me up so nicely.

> Bandages **(as suggested by OP)**

Comment: Dead on except for the last two. Was thinking of bandanna (for heists/outlaws) and bandages. But I think I could have worded those lines better. For the knot one I was thinking more along the lines of not "a head", but your interpretation is still correct. Nice work

Comment: Ah yes, I did think of bandanna at some point but forgot to include it. I'll put those two in at the end as they explain it much better.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a kinda partial answer...is it a

> Choir group / band ?

As,

Come together singing let it be,
And gather that which is free,

> A choir is a group of people for singing / reciting

As a child a simple weapon,
To best not be in possession,

> ... (to be explored)

Follow so you can ride with me,
Let us play and move exactly,

> Orchestrating / synchronizing voices/sounds is the key for a good choir/band

A no-good-doer finishes it,
Forging not ahead makes your commit,

> If someone in the group misses a note / rhythm he becomes no-good-doer and also the later line means the same

A mystery is all I can see,
As you dress me up so nicely.

> Usually choir groups are dressed up attractively (though not sure about mystery in this)

Comment: Each line can be taken separately. But it's not a choir.